How to change document printing quality in WinUI3?
I'm using an example of Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing.
It works, but printed document resolution is too low. I tried to make "Print to PDF", then print .pdf document, and it works good.  How to change printing resolution programatically (there not resolution property in default printing UI)?

There's a "CustomPrintDocument" sample here https://github.com/smourier/XpsPrintSamples that may do what you need
